# How can I convert a non-CMS web application to a Sitefinity managed application?

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I am in the process of converting a web application that has been in play for some time into a Sitefinity 4 managed site. There is plenty of documentation on how to use the software to CREATE a new site, but I've found precious little that describes the process of how to migrate from non-cms to Sitefinity.

So - specifically, I would like some guidance on the process of conversion from non-managed to managed. I've been searching google and the Sitefinity forums, etc. but finding nothing except how to migrate from one version of Sitefinity to another - not what I'm trying to do.

Any leads for web sites to visit or documentation pages to read would be very helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to move content from existing app into Sitefinity driven app, or do you want to integrate your app with Sitefinity?

Comment: Trying to transition from non-managed to having Sitefinity manage the whole site. The problem is doing it in stages. If we have Sitefinity at the root of the application, we cannot, according to Sitefinity, have any pages not managed by SF. We do not have the resources to do a complete transition to SF managed site, so we want to determine if and if so, how, we can partially manage content in a site, allowing us the ability to use .aspx pages with code behind until we can convert them to SF modules, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to bite the bullet and invest more resources at the beginning of your project and not release anything for some period of time. You won't be able to drive your car without fundamental components. The same principle applies here.

Whatever your requirements are, you will either have to hack around the CMS and then fix the hacks later, or do it properly from the very start.

1. Look at your existing site and break it down into smaller chunks
2. Consult Sitefinity documentation/partners/freelancers on how your existing content can be migrated onto Sitefinity platform
3. Task up the migration and start implementing

This is very rough guideline, but so are your requirements.

To summarise, there is no quick way. You'll have to do it properly form the start, or invest more resources later on bug/hack fixing.

Answer (score 1):

> If we have Sitefinity at the root of the application, we cannot,
>   according to Sitefinity, have any pages not managed by SF

That's not entirely correct. Sitefinity allows you to add "external pages", meaning that you can create odes in your sitemap which would like to external pages. Thus, your navigation in Sitefinity would show a complete website page structure, while some of the pages in that structure would actually be linking to external ones.

It would be absolutely easy and quick task to create your page structure programatically.

Comment: We were hoping to have the URLs look the same as they were before to visitors who have been on the site prior. I created links to "external" pages and they show a different "site" URL. Is there a way to overcome that?

Answer (score 1):

actually this is quite simple to achieve. Sitefinity is completely dynamic CMS (meaning, no real files). The implementation uses RoutingEngine and VirtualPathProvider to achieve this. What this in reality means is that you have two solid and standard extension points to split the site in "sitefinity managed part" and "custom managed part".

So, a very simple way to do this is to simply register a route (more info here: [ASP.NET routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)) before the SitefinityPageRoute, as SitefinityPageRoute will throw 404 if it cannot find a page.

So, let's say you register a route "~/mystuff" before SitefinityPageRoute, all the requests that start with "~/mystuff" will first go to your RouteHandler where you can decide to handle them (write to http response) or do nothing and let it fell down to Sitefinity routes.

Another way is of course to implement a custom VirtualPathProvider, however, this may be an overkill if you simply want some pages to be handled differently.

All this being said, it's obvious that pages not handled by Sitefinity will not be handled by Sitefinity :) (so, no page editor, no workflows, no translations, no widgets, no templates, no themes).